# JQuery: Done() after if-else

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Using `ajax calls` we have the ability to perform actions after it hase run using the `done()-function`

```
$.ajax({
        .....
      })
 .done ( function(data) {
        ..... (manipulate data using $.ajax result
      })
```

Right now I have an `if-else` clause with an `ajax-embedded` in it.

```
  if (some condition)
  { //Standard  HTML-element/tag manipulation
       $("#obj1").append('<a class="trigger">Click Me </trigger>');
       $(".SomeClass").remove();
       ......
  }
  else
  { 
     //HTML-element/tag manipulation after $.ajax-call 
     $.ajax({
       //perform ajax-call
     })
     .done(function (data) {
          $("#obj1").append('<a class="trigger">' data.someProp '</trigger>');
      })
  }

  //Perform actions: Part2
  $(".trigger").Click(function() { Somefunction() });
```

I was wondering if Jquery offers a way to make the execution of the `functions in Part2` halt until all actions inside the `if-else` are completed (including the `$.ajax`)?. I can't seem to find anything around this using google (most likely i'm just using the wrong keywords).

I hope my question is understandable for everyone. If  you need further information, don't hesitate to comment.

Comment: Hum... it might not be the most elegant solution, but I guess you could duplicate the call to PART2 in each branch of the condition. Have you tried that?

Comment: Why not wrap the functions in `part2` inside a function and call that from the `if` branch and from the `done` function in the `else` branch?

Comment: Yes, But that produces a reasoable amount of duplicate code, which i would love to avoid. @ZiNNED indeed an elegant yet simple solution. That was my first idea aswell. yet i could resist to ask for an alternative. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery promise in this case.  http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

```
var dfd = null; 

if (some condition)
  { //Standard  HTML-element/tag manipulation
       $("#obj1").append('<a class="trigger">Click Me </trigger>');
       $(".SomeClass").remove();
       ......
      //Create Deferred object and resolve immediately
      dfd = $.Deferred();
      dfd.resolve();
  }
  else
  { 
     //HTML-element/tag manipulation after $.ajax-call 
    //$.ajax returns Deferred 
    dfd = $.ajax({
       //perform ajax-call
     })
     .done(function (data) {
          $("#obj1").append('<a class="trigger">' data.someProp '</trigger>');
      })
  }

  //Use when for waiting the Deferred to get resolved
  $.when(dfd).then(function(){
        //Perform actions: Part2
       $(".trigger").Click(function() { Somefunction() });
  })
```

Comment: When debugging `.when` still gets executed before `.done`. But the `When` might indeed be thing i need. Time for me to do some further research.

Comment: Corrected syntax of using when-then. Check if this works for you. I am not sure which one is called before done or then...

Comment: Sweet! It does! Cheers Mate!

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
  if (some condition)
  { //Standard  HTML-element/tag manipulation
       $("#obj1").append('<a class="trigger">Click Me </trigger>');
       $(".SomeClass").remove();
       ......
       Part2();
  }
  else
  { 
     //HTML-element/tag manipulation after $.ajax-call 
     $.ajax({
       //perform ajax-call
     })
     .done(function (data) {
          $("#obj1").append('<a class="trigger">' data.someProp '</trigger>');
          Part2();
      })
  }

function Part2()
{
    $(".trigger").Click(function() { Somefunction() });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use 'synchronous AJAX requests'

```
    //HTML-element/tag manipulation after $.ajax-call 
     $.ajax({
       //perform ajax-call
       **async: false**
     })
     .done(function (data) {
          $("#obj1").append('<a class="trigger">' data.someProp '</trigger>');
      })
```

Comment: A valable solution indeed! Yet i prefer @vishwanath solution